# WCF 4.0 SOA Commit as Transcation

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-3.5, soa

In WCF 4.0, How  can I commit  3 different service operation as a single Transaction? (Commit in SOA)

I have 3 different WCF service like below, Each service method invokes DB operation

```
service1.CreateEmployee();

service2.SendSetupRequestForEmployee();

service3.GiveOfficePermissionToEmployee();
```

Even if one operation fails entire thing should be rolled back...any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you have three separate service (based on code it looks like it)? Or just three operations on a single service (makes more sense to me)?

Comment: It is 3 different service altogether, For sample i put that code.

Comment: Those 3 services are connected to the same database?

Comment: Yes, It is connected to same DB.  Each service represents different module, I use Entity Framework for updating the DB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer:  Make your service calls under a `TransactionScope`, and make sure the calls themselves are set up to run under transactions.

**TLDR** read this article [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFTransactions.aspx).

Basically, you need to decorate your Operation Contract method as such:

```
[TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Allowed)]
void MyWcfServiceCall() {...}
```

and the service method call itself with:

```
[OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
void MyWcfServiceCall() {...}
```

and call under a `TransactionScope`

```
using (TransactionScope tx = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew)) {
    myServiceClient.MyWcfServiceCall();
    myOtherServiceClient.MyOtherWcfServiceCall();
    tx.Complete();
}
```

in your config file for the bindings, set transactionFlow to `true`:

```
<bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MyServiceBinding" transactionFlow="true" ... />
    </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked out, Had issue setting up "Distributed Transaction Manager" for both the servers, after that it worked fine.